# Oracle dump (.dmp) file format

Tags: oracle, format, rdbms, dmp

I am wondering about how is the internal format of a .dmp file (dump file, or backup and restoration file) used by Oracle RBMS.

Does it follow any standard? Is it optimized in any way?

Thanks.

**Edited:**

Oracle version: 11g

Comment: You should indicate the Oracle version your after. I'm no expert, but it looks like the format changed between version 9 and 10 (from binary to text? - I'm not sure).

Comment: @Christian.K - I think you're seeing the difference between the old `exp` dump and newer `expdp` (data pump) dump files. Neither format is publicly documented though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does it follow any standard.*

Yes - the one that Oracle defined for their export format.

> *It it optimized in any way*

You can compress the data, if that's what you mean.
See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#BABCAJHC

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two different formats

> Although Data Pump Export (expdp) functionality is similar to that of
>   the original Export utility (exp), they are completely separate
>   utilities and their files are not compatible.

Does it follow any standard? : The file format is proprietary. I did not find any rogue documentation on the format online...

> The dump file set is made up of one or more disk files that contain
>   table data, database object metadata, and control information. The
>   files are written in a proprietary, binary format.

Is it optimized?
Answered by a_horse_with_no_name.

**Source:** https://docs.oracle.com/html/B28319_02/dp_export.htm